# How do I protect against WPA de-authentication attacks?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, networking, wireless-router, wpa

Someone is constantly sending deauth packets to me.... =(

Comment: The only real defense is to use Ethernet, turn off the WiFi. Or Use WPA2 encryption, and make sure that you are using a strong network key.

Comment: Nope, WPA2-PSK, like WPA-PSK, is still susceptible to deauth attacks.

Comment: lol, using ethernet isn't a solution to a wireless problem =p

Comment: Is there a way to maybe ignore de-auth packets? I know sometimes they are legit... BUt I'm not clear on when.... maybe if there was a way to detect when they were from the router... or something... not ... that... that also couldn't be forged... bah... =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use WPA(2)-EAP (extensible authentication protocol, sometimes called "enterprise") instead of WPA(2)-PSK (pre-shared key, sometimes called "personal"), you can make sure that your wireless is not snooped and that deauth packets will not open avenues of attack.  EAP-TLS allows the client to authenticate the AP and vice versa, and each client can have its own secret key.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Management Frame Protection, or MFP. Defined in ieee 802.11w, 2009. Not everything supports it yet, and Cisco has their own version.

Comment: Would it be possible to hyperlink to an explanation of the Cisco version?